# IEqualityComparer Exception with Linq (NotSupportedException)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I was doing a custom Comparer to compare two classes in a Linq query like this one:

```
Table<Info> table = context.GetTable<Info>();
bool infoAlreadyExists = table.Contains(info, new MyComparer());
```

This is my comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Info>
{

    #region IEqualityComparer<Info> Member

    public bool Equals(Info x, Info y)
    {
        return x.Content == y.Content;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Info obj)
    {
        return obj.Content.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The problem is that I get an exception. **`[System.NotSupportedException]`**

The exception tells me that a not supported overload for the `Contains` operator was found. Do I do something wrong or is it really NotSupported? I couldn't find anything on the documentation.

This is the definition of the overload I am trying to use of the contains method.

```
public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, TSource item, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer);
```

Comment: Are you using Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities?

Comment: I am using Linq-To-Sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That version of `Contains` method is not supported.You can see the full list here:

- [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx)

So you need to perform this operation in memory, you can use `AsEnumerable` for that.

But in this case it seems you don't need that equality comparer. You can just use the below query to get the same result:

```
table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content == info.Content) != null;
```

Comment: It's not clear what LINQ provider he's using. But afaik also `Linq-To-SQL` does not support it.

Comment: This is the approach I am using right now. I just wondered why the other way did not work. Thanks for confirming that it is not supported.